# Как сделать блок одиинаковой высоты с другими блоками?

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

Я использую owl-carousel и мне нужно сделать так, чтобы все owl-item были одинаковый высоты, но один из блоков не поддается. Как прировнять его к высоты всех блоков, но чтобы он не опускался ниже картинок других блоков?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Весь код https://jsfiddle.net/p512awsm/

Сам сайт http://ilyin1ib.beget.tech/

```js
$(".spaces-gal.owl-carousel").owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        slideSpeed: 9000,
        items: 3,
        autoHeight: true,
        loop: true,
        nav: true,
        navText: ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-left'></i>", "<i class='fas fa-chevron-right'></i>"],
        center: true,
        dots: false,
        responsiveClass: true,
        smartSpeed: 400,
        margin: 30,
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1,
                margin: 0,
                dots: false,
                nav: true
            },
            768: {}
        }
    });
```

```css
.space-title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.space-title h3 {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #10375c;
  font-size: 40px;
}
.space-title p {
  color: #9a9a9a;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 452px;
  width: 100%;
}
.space-title .plug {
  background-color: red;
}
.space-slide.one {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.space-slide.two {
  background-color: #10375c;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  max-height: 407px;
}
.space-slide.two h4 {
  font-family: 'Lora', serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 32px;
  color: #fff;
}
.space-slide.two p {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
  max-width: 253px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="spaces">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="space-title">
                    <h3>Our Spaces</h3>
                    <p>Our space is designed to give you a different experience when working with your team or personally</p>
                    <div class="plug">lorem</div>
                </div>
                <div class="spaces-gal owl-carousel">
                    <div class="space-slide one">
                        <img src="img/space-1.jpg" alt="1">
                        <span>Working with team</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space-slide two">
                        <h4>Private Space</h4>
                        <p>Comfortable space, Full speed wifi, Free coffe & Snack and many more</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space-slide three">
                        <img src="img/space-3.jpg" alt="3">
                        <span>Custom Office</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.owl-stage классу задайте флекс, тогда элементы выстроятся в одну высоту https://monosnap.com/file/UFo5wlZv4ikeuacVZSzTE0FOsW4y7l , а самому синему блоку https://monosnap.com/file/bnGcNYhTDK5JA1ZhCU40wYJTvhXlBI